# how to get 10 mid users in an sql table sorted by count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables with the following schema:

**Table A**

```
usernName, email (one email per user)
```

**Table B**

```
userName, product (many products per user)
```

I want to write a query that returns the `userName + email` of the 10 users with the biggest number of products, 10 users in the middle and 10 users with the smallest number of products.

I verify in advance that there are more than 30 records (to avoid duplication)

I know `groupby` won't help me. Should I use rank with `partitionby`?
What is the difference between `groupby` and `partitionby`?

How should I write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should logically be equivalent to [@Quassnoi's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10671613/297408) but is built in such a way as to enable you to parametrise the `10` easily (it is replaced with `@cnt` below):

```
SELECT
  userName,
  email
FROM (
  SELECT
    A.userName,
    A.email,
    rnAsc    = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC),
    rnDesc   = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
  FROM A
    INNER JOIN B ON A.userName = B.userName
  GROUP BY
    A.userName,
    A.email
) s
WHERE rnAsc  <= @cnt
   OR rnDesc <= @cnt
   OR rnAsc - rnDesc BETWEEN -@cnt AND @cnt - 1
;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  userName, email
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY products DESC) rn,
                COUNT(*) OVER () AS cnt
        FROM    (
                SELECT  userName, email, products
                FROM    a
                CROSS APPLY
                        (
                        SELECT  COUNT(*) products        
                        FROM    b
                        WHERE   b.userName = a.userName
                        ) p
                )
        ) q
WHERE   rn <= 10
        OR
        rn >= cnt - 10
        OR
        rn BETWEEN cnt / 2 - 5 AND cnt / 2 + 4
```